# What is a BPS state and why is it the cohomology of a moduli space?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, mp.mathematical-physics, supersymmetry

The notion of a [*BPS state*](https://web.ma.utexas.edu/users/neitzke/expos/bps-lectures.pdf) has existed in physics for a long time: I do not understand it completely, but I get the impression they are the supersymmetric analogue of ground states, and then physicists wrote down explicit formulas giving an algebra structure to the vector space of these.

To mathematicise this, Kontsevich and Soibelman [introduced](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1006.2706.pdf) an algebra structure on the cohomology $\text{H}^\cdot(M_\mathcal{A})$ of the moduli space $M_\mathcal{A}$ of a certain abelian category $\mathcal{A}$ (and variations of this with vanishing cyc.les). There are now many other versions of this, for instance [using Borel-Moore homology](https://arxiv.org/abs/1901.07641)

---

My question is a posteriori why these two stories/objects should be related at all. e.g. is there a physical interpretation of $\mathcal{A}$, of $M_\mathcal{A}$, of the moduli space of extensions, or of taking cohomology? Conversely, when $\mathcal{A}$ is coherent sheaves on a scheme or representations of a quiver with potential, what is the QFT whose space of BPS states gives $\text{H}^\cdot(M_\mathcal{A})$ or $\text{H}_\cdot^{BM}(M_\mathcal{A})$, in the cases when there is a Hall algebra structure on these?

Maybe not all of these individual questions are known/answerable, but hopefully they give a flavour of the sort of answer I'm looking for.

Comment: This is a good question - see the closely related https://mathoverflow.net/questions/111868/the-use-of-hall-algebras-in-physics -  but really there are two separate issues: the one you ask (what are BPS states/why are they realized in cohomology of moduli spaces) and the implied one (why is there an algebra structure on BPS states - first identified by Harvey-Moore - and why should it be realized mathematically as a Hall algebra).

Comment: The Clay monograph [Mirror Symmetry](https://www.claymath.org/publications/online-books) may help. Try reading Chapters 18 and 33.